# Wrong timezone in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, centos7, php-7.2

PHP is printing wrong timezone. I've checked nearly everything. I will describe what I've checked and I am running.
Centos 7, PHP 7.2, Apache 2.4.6, Wordpress 5.1
Centos has America/Toronto timezone. Showing the time exactly. Wordpress has the same timezone. Post time also shows the correct time. Fixed time in php.ini  -
date.timezone = "America/Toronto" (I made changes in the effective php.ini)
Still when I want to run this code - `date('m/d/Y h:i:s a')` it give me UTC(which is not Toronto timezone) time. What am I missing?

Edit: I restarted server several times during making these changes

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart everything after making those changes to the system file?

Comment: I restarted server several times during making these changes

Comment: Did you upgrade from a previous PHP version? If so, your new installation might still be pointing to the old version rather than the newer one. Edit: as pointed out in more detail by @Phil

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no, the server had php 7.2 running from the beginning. It's a new server

Comment: @Phil that's why I wrote "effective", meaning I checked phpinfo and then made my changes

Comment: Now this starts to get a bit funky. Ok, so maybe we need to see a minimal example of how you're using this. Seeing this might be Wordpress related, I won't be able to help you there. Maybe Wordpress has some of its own thing happening, that I don't know.

Comment: @Phil there is only one php version installed. checked in my browser. and there is only one line that says "Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini", there are no other "Loaded Configuration File" in that page

Comment: Run `echo date_default_timezone_get();` and `echo ini_get('date.timezone');` in your script. (Not from the command line.) What do you get?

Comment: Maybe try `America/New_York`? I'm picking at straws here of course. It's the same timezone though.

Comment: @Phil phpinfo shows "Default timezone America/Toronto"

Comment: @AlexHowansky `date_default_timezone_get()` shows UTC. `ini_get('date.timezone')` shows America/Toronto

Comment: Ok then, I think that means that WordPress is using `date_default_timezone_set()` to override the default.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Heh, funny you should mention Wordpress, as [did I...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001396/wrong-timezone-in-php#comment94839663_54001396) earlier which made my spidey sense tingle lol.

Comment: @Phil couldn't find any other php.ini path in phpinfo(). How can I look for other ini files?

Comment: @AsifurRahman never mind, wild goose chase. The output from `phpinfo()` would tell you of any others though

Comment: Should this be tagged as "wordpress"?

Comment: @AlexHowansky and Funkfortyniner how can I fix the wordpress default timezone set? As I've mentioned in my post, wordpress settings is set to America/Toronto and wordpress post times are also showing correct time

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I tagged wordpress

Comment: As I said, if this is a Wordpress issue, I can't help. I don't know Wordpress from Adam, if I can say *lol*

Comment: Don't fix it. See [this](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/vip-go/use-current_time-not-date_default_timezone_set/).

Comment: @Phil I tried running `echo date_default_timezone_set();` outside of wordpress environment and it looks working fine. Just not in wordpress

Comment: @AlexHowansky Looks like I need to update hell lot of codes(where I used date('m/d/Y h:i:s a')) thanks for the tip

Comment: If this fixes what @AlexHowansky suggested in the link he found, I feel it'd only be fair that he submits an answer for this, IMHO.

Comment: Agree with @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Ah, @Phil found a duplicate for it.